# How to Put Ages into intervals

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a list of ages in an existing dataframe. I would like to put these ages into intervals/Age Groups such as (10-20), (20-30),etc. Please see excample below
[image]

I am unsure where to begin coding this as i get an "bins" errors when using all bins related code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
def checkAgeRange(age):
    las_dig=age%10
    range_age=str.format('{0}-{1}',age-las_dig,((age-las_dig)+10))
    return range_age

d={'AGE':[19,13,45,65,23,12,28]}
dataFrame= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dataFrame['AgeGroup']=dataFrame['AGE'].apply(checkAgeRange)
print(dataFrame)

# Output:   AGE AgeGroup
        0   19    10-20
        1   13    10-20
        2   45    40-50
        3   65    60-70
        4   23    20-30
        5   12    10-20
        6   28    20-30
```

Some explanation of code above:

```
d={'AGE':[19,13,45,65,23,12,28]}
dataFrame= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# Making a simple dataframe here

dataFrame['AgeGroup']=dataFrame['AGE'].apply(checkAgeRange)
# applying our checkAgeRange function here

def checkAgeRange(age):
las_dig=age%10
range_age=str.format('{0}-{1}',age-las_dig,((age-las_dig)+10))
return range_age
# This method extracts the las digit from age and then forms the range as a string. You can change the data-structure here according to your needs.
```

**Hope this answers your question. Cheers!**